# How can I use threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use `Thread` in Java. I create a class that extend `Thread` and it's fine, but the problem is, when call this `Thread`, I don't know the number of instances of this class, since the user must enter this number.  For example:

```
multiThread multiThreadInstance = new multiThread(/* number entered from user */);
multiThreadInstance.start();
```

This will call this thread once, but if i write:

```
multiThread multiThreadInstance1 = new multiThread(/* number entered from user */)
multiThreadInstance1.start()   
multiThread multiThreadInstance2 = new multiThread(/* number entered from user */)
multiThreadInstance2.start()
```

This will call it twice at the same time, and so on.

If I put it in a `for` loop, then if user enters 3 for example, then `start1` runs, when `start1` finishes, `start2` runs, when `start2` finishes, `start3` runs.  I need to keep these instances of thread running in at the same time.  How can i do this?

Comment: Sorry if I missed something but I'm not sure too understand what your problem. First of all is the *number entered from the user* significant in your question? All the examples in your questions seems to be working. Could you post the code for your loop implementation and tell us what's not working or what you do not know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use java high level concurrency utilities to do this. Look at countdownlatches and executors. The following is a code that would do what you want. I recommend you read up on java concurrency utilities.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ConcurrentTimer {
    private ConcurrentTimer() { } // Noninstantiable

    public static long time(Executor executor, int concurrency,
            final Runnable action) throws InterruptedException {
        final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
        final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);

        for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ready.countDown(); // Tell timer we're ready
                    try {
                        start.await(); // Wait till peers are ready
                        action.run();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    } finally {
                        done.countDown();  // Tell timer we're done
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        ready.await();     // Wait for all workers to be ready
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        start.countDown(); // And they're off!
        done.await();      // Wait for all workers to finish
        return System.nanoTime() - startNanos;
    }
}
```

---

A runnable version of the code example provided above: (Edited)

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ConcurrentTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            Runnable action = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        System.out.println("Thread Running");

                    }
                };

            time (3, action);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private ConcurrentTimer() { } // Noninstantiable

    public static long time(int concurrency,
            final Runnable action) throws InterruptedException {

        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);


        final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
        final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);

        for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ready.countDown(); // Tell timer we're ready
                    try {
                        start.await(); // Wait till peers are ready
                        action.run();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    } finally {
                        done.countDown();  // Tell timer we're done
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        ready.await();     // Wait for all workers to be ready
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        start.countDown(); // And they're off!
        done.await();      // Wait for all workers to finish
        return System.nanoTime() - startNanos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course that was for your reference. i have added a runnable code complete with main.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have **accidentally overridden the `start()` method** in `Thread`. Make sure it is the `run()` method you're overriding.

If you override the `start()` method with your own implementation, you "remove the magic" of the `Thread` class. The magic lies in `start()` which starts the execution of the `run()` method in a fresh thread, so keep your own code in `run()`.

Comment: i put my own code in run method, when i say multiThreadInstance.start()  run method works

Comment: do you have any synchronization in your run method? such as `wait`/`notify` for instance.

Comment: no there are no synchronization in my run method, i have only sleep method

Comment: Post your entire code in for instance pastebin.com and I'll have a look at it.